# Using SVG files as a React Component in a CRA app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to import an svg file but as a react component but I can't see the actual icon. I expect to see a **Home Icon** but all I'm seeing is a black-filled figure.

**What I tried**

```
import {ReactComponent as Home} from '../assets/svgs/home.svg'; 
import {List, ListItem, ListItemIcon} from '@material-ui/core'; 

<List>
 {['Home', 'Video', 'Music', 'Sound', 'Painting', 'Images', 'Heritage', 'Fashion'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <Home/> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
      ))}
<List/>
```

**My SVG File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="25px" height="25px">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M0 2560 l0 -2560 2560 0 2560 0 0 2560 0 2560 -2560 0 -2560 0 0
-2560z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**What I'm getting**

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: How about using: `import Home from '../assets/svgs/home.svg'; 
`?

Comment: @TasosBu, when I do as you say, I get this error: ```InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/home.8cdaa428.svg') is not a valid name.```

Comment: Hope this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/) will help you to understand.

Comment: Oh yeah, you use CRA. Seems like the way you imported it should work. Can you do the checks that Aydin posted as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your SVG on this site: http://svg.enshrined.co.uk/

The SVG itself is broken I suggest you find another.

[Your SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNaka.png)

Comment: I checked the path and used the Chrome dev tools but everything looks fine.

Comment: You probably missing any other content even though the path is right

Comment: Thanks to y'all. The SVG was broken and it ruined everything. I tried another converter as I was converting PNG to SVG and it gave me the right SVG file  and I got it working.